# How to access a repository from a case class in dependency injection

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework

We are busy upgrading some play 2.3 (anorm) apps. In our case classes, we have many convenience methods or lazy vals which do things such as look up the "parents" or "children" of an instance. The ones in question are at the model layer and often make calls to methods in a companion object which will go to the DB. For example, currently we might have:

```scala
case class Product(id:Int, name:String, productTypeId:Int) {
  lazy val productType = ProductType.findById(productTypeId).getOrElse(ProductType())
}
```

Then, whenever one has an instance of a `Product`, you can simple refer to `product.productType`, be it in a view, a controller, another model, etc.

If producType were a method rather than a lazy val, it would seem possible to have an implicit parameter. So `productType` might become:

```scala
def productType()(implicit productTypeRepository:ProductTypeRepository) = productTypeRepository.findById(productTypeId).getOrElse(ProductType())
```

Then every place that references this (now) `product.productType()` would have to have the `productTypeRepository` implicit in scope. The value of the lazy val, however, seems to be lost in this case.

It is not clear in a dependency injection world, how (or even whether) to implement these. How would one inject an instance of `ProductTypeRepository` into the case class? Or is there another way of achieving this approach?

Comment: In "Play framework world" (and not only) you don't inject a repository in a case class. The case class represents the model but is not responsible to retrieve data.

Comment: See idiomatic usage of Play + Anorm: https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/tree/2.8.x/play-scala-anorm-example

Comment: @GaëlJ Thanks for that - I now have the project running. In the sample, if you wanted to access the company for a specific computer, it's convenient to be able to say `computer.company`. (computer is an instance so has an id from a specific context, no?) We make extensive use of lazy vals like this. A user's licence's productType might be retrieved with something like userLicence.licence.productCapability.product.productType, for example. I'm trying to figure out what that is going to look like in the future - can I make this work or will we be refactoring every single one of these references.

Comment: Well you can make it work by storing a reference to the repository in each instance of the case class. But this really does not feel like the Play/Scala way of doing things IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems that classes can have implicit parameters, separately from their ordinary parameters. This is something I haven't seen before. In this case, it may be as simple as defining the required implicits, for example:

```scala
case class Product(id:Int, name:String, productTypeId:Int) (implicit productTypeRepository:ProductTypeRepository){
  lazy val productType = ProductTypeRepository.findById(productTypeId).getOrElse(ProductType())
}
```

Then in any code that constructs new instances of the case class, an implicit `productTypeRepository` will have to be available. This doesn't seem to break any rules for me - it's just saying that whenever you want to create an instance of a case class, you need to make available any dependencies that it requires.

In fact, simple references (`product.productType`) remain intact (no changes to their containing object signatures even)! Places that create instances should have the dependencies available. E.g. the controller in this case:

```scala
class Products @Inject()(productRepository: Product,
  cc: MessagesControllerComponents)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext,
  productTypeRepository: ProductTypeRepository) //-- required to instantiate Product

  ...
  val product = Product(id,name,productTypeId)
```